# Cloth simulation: Gaps between meshes sewing springs

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm modelling a t-shirt, but I get these gaps between the meshes that are being sewed with Sewing Springs. It is as the springs aren't tight enough, but if I adjust the Sewing Force nothing really happens in term of the gaps.

[image]

Comment: I can't replicate this problem - can you upload your blend file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and edit your question to include the link to the file.

Comment: I have the same problem in Blender 2.8. So far I found it happens when using Self collision and the gap is very likely the (Minimum) Distance set in the Self collsion section. Seems to me like a bug as one probably doesn't want this minimum to be applied on sewn vertices.

Comment: I filed this as a bug and it was confirmed by the developers. More info here: https://developer.blender.org/T65568

Comment: have you tried giving a small value like -0.2 to the shrinking factor? It's under "shape" in the physics tab for the cloth simulation

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem too, I was able to fix it by applying the subdivision surface modifier and manually joining the vertices which where created by it, and then re-simulating again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and found that the problem was not having enough sew edges. ie add loopcuts to the parts that are being sewn together and connect them so that you have more stitches. once you have enough the seam will pull fully together.
(this fix assumes that there is enough "fabric" as in the gap is not caused because the fabric is not stretching around the model)

Answer (score 0):

As Vit Kovalcik said in the comments, self collision distance can cause the issue.

Also make sure that your sewing max force is high enough.